# Angular JS -: Scope Lost after formating through directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am facing an Issue when I am trying to format a json date to normal date by using a directive.

I am fairly new to Angular, Please suggest what am I missing?

My Html goes like this:

```
 <form ng-submit="UpdateShipment()">
       <input type="text"  format-Date ng-model="old.ship_date" />
       <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save" />
 </form>
```

Directive :

```
.directive('formatDate', function () {

return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope : {'ngModel' : '='},
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelController) {

        ngModelController.$formatters.unshift(function (valueFromModel) {

            if (angular.isUndefined(valueFromModel)) {
                return valueFromModel;
            }
            var date = new Date(parseInt(valueFromModel.substr(6)));
        return date.toLocaleDateString();
        });
    }
};
});
```

Controller :

```
        $scope.UpdateShipment = function () {
        console.log($scope.old.ship_date) //On Form Submit getting old Json Format date 
        //$http call here
        }
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: you cannot use isolated scope when using ng-model controller

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using isolated scope with ng-model controller but if your insist you have to use $parent property inside ng-model

```
 <input type="text"  format-Date ng-model="$parent.old.ship_date" />
```

Comment: I did what you have mentioned, but same results.

Comment: could you set up your fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8qdqM/7

I tried to set up a fiddle but it is giving a minor error , Hope you can trouble shoot that too. Thanks